# Finding expressions for area elements

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If you consider a rectangle of some general length $x$ and width $y$, we can say:

$A=xy$

$\Rightarrow dA=ydx + xdy$

$\Rightarrow\int dA=\int^X _0 ydx + \int_0 ^Y xdy$

$=2XY$

Why does this give twice the area?

Answer (score 1):

If $A = xy$ then $\frac{dA}{dx} = y$ and  $\frac{dA}{dy} = x$. So $dA +dA= y dx + x dy$

There is another way to compute the area. You can start from the Green's theorem. Let C be a simple, closed, regular plane curve with interior region $\it{R}$ and let (P(x,y),Q(x,y)) a differentiable vector field. The Green's theorem says that:
\begin{equation}
\int_C Pdx/Q dy =\int\int_{\it{R}} \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right) dx dy
\end{equation} 
If in each of thys integral one simply choose a vector field such that
\begin{equation}
 \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right) =1
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
A = \int_C x dy =-\int_C y dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_C x dy - y dx
\end{equation}
The three integrals are obtained by substituting:
$(P(x,y),Q(x,y))=(0,x); (P(x,y),Q(x,y))=(-y,0)$ and $(P(x,y),Q(x,y))=\frac{1}{2} (-y,x)$.

Comment: But where in my working have I made a mistake? I can't see any fault in the working, although thanks to your answer I see why I am getting twice the area, I can't link it with any mistake in my working.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule that leads you from the second to the third of your formulas.

You start with the function 
$$A(x,y):=xy\ .$$
This function has a first differential
$$dA=A_x\>dx+A_y\>dy=y\>dx+x\>dy\ .\tag{1}$$
In order to get back the value of $A(u,v)$ at a point $(u,v)$ in the first quadrant through integration of $dA$ from $A(0,0)=0$   to $(u,v)$  we have to choose a path $\gamma$ from $(0,0)$ to $(u,v)$, and to integrate $(1)$ along $\gamma$. Choose
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto \bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr):=(tu,tv)\qquad(0\leq t\leq 1)\ .$$
Then $(1)$ gives
$$dx=u\>dt,\qquad dy=v\>dt,\qquad dA=t v\, u\>dt+tu\,v\>dt=2t\,uv\>dt\ .$$
It follows that
$$A(u,v)=A(0,0)+\int_\gamma dA=0+\int_0^1 2t\,uv\>dt=uv\ ,$$
as expected.

Answer (score 0):

@Christian Blatter's answer is excellent. Here I wish to outline another path of integration.

We wish to calculate $A(u,v)$ by integrating $dA = ydx + x dy$ along a path. Let's choose the (piecewise smooth) path $\gamma$, which starts from $(0,0)$ and moves horizontally to $(u,0)$, and then moves vertically to $(u,v)$ (draw a picture). Then by the Fundamental theorem of calculus (or the gradient theorem or whatever this theorem is called),
\begin{align}
A(u,v) &= A(0,0) + \int_{\gamma} dA \\
&= 0 + \int_{\gamma} (y\, dx + x\, dy)
\end{align}
Now, notice that on the horizontal portion from $(0,0)$ to $(u,0)$, we have $y=0$, so, $dy = 0$ as well; hence
\begin{align}
y \, dx + x \, dy = 0 
\end{align}
Thus, integrating over this portion of the curve contributes nothing to the total. In the vertical part of the curve from $(u,0)$ to $(u,v)$, $x$ is held fixed at $x=u$, which means $dx = 0$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
y\, dx + x \, dy = y(0) + u\, dy = u \, dy
\end{align}
Integrating from $y=0$ to $y=v$ gives $\int_0^v u \, dy = uv$. So, indeed, $A(u,v) = 0 + uv = uv$.

---

By the way, if you wish, you can carry out the exact same computation in more detail if my manipulations of $dx$ and $dy$ worries you, by writing down an explicit parametrization: $\gamma: [0, u+v] \to \Bbb{R}^2$,
\begin{align}
\gamma(t) &:= 
\begin{cases}
(t, 0) & \text{if $0 \leq t \leq u$} \\
(u,t) & \text{if $u \leq t \leq u + v$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
I shall write $\gamma_x$ and $\gamma_y$ to mean the $x$ and $y$ components of the curve $\gamma$. As above, by the FTC, we have:
\begin{align}
A(u,v) &= A(0,0) + \int_{\gamma} dA \\
&= 0 + \int_{\gamma} y \, dx + x \, dy \\
&= \int_0^{u+v} \left[\gamma_y(t) \cdot \gamma_x'(t) + \gamma_x(t) \cdot \gamma_y'(t) \right] \, dt \\
&= \int_0^{u} \left[\gamma_y(t) \cdot \gamma_x'(t) + \gamma_x(t) \cdot \gamma_y'(t) \right] \, dt + \int_u^{u+v} \left[\gamma_y(t) \cdot \gamma_x'(t) + \gamma_x(t) \cdot \gamma_y'(t) \right] \, dt \\
&= \int_0^u \left[ 0 \cdot 1 + t \cdot 0\right] \, dt + \int_u^{u+v} \left[ t \cdot 0 + u \cdot 1\right] \, dt \\
&= 0 + uv \\
&= uv
\end{align}